# Simplification error on fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

$$\frac{7 !-6 !+5 ! \cdot 4 !}{6 !}$$ is the fraction I want to evaluate. Dealing with this, I come up with the following wrong expansion. What point do I forget?

$$ = \frac{4! \cdot{\color{Green} (}(5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7-5 \cdot 6)+5\color{Green} )}{6!} $$

$$=  \frac{4! \cdot((210-30)+5)}{6!}$$

$$
=  \frac{4! \cdot185}{6!} = \frac{185}{5\cdot6}$$

Comment: It should be $(5.6.7-5.6)+5{!}$ instead of $(5.6.7-5.6)+5$

Comment: @Asher2211 ouch! Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you factor $5!$ out of the numerator instead of $4!$?  Or even $6!$?

Comment: @B.Goddard why sir?

Comment: Note that $5!4! = 5!\cdot 6\cdot 4 = 6!\cdot 4.$  So the numerator factors as $6!( 7 -1 +4)$  and the $6!$ cancel.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

$$\frac{4!(5\cdot6\cdot7-5\cdot6+5!)}{6!}$$

This is since you have the term $5!\cdot4!$ where you can factor out a $4!$ term.

$$=\frac{4!(5\cdot6\cdot7-5\cdot6+5!)}{6!}$$
$$=\frac{4!(180 + 120)}{6!}$$
$$=\frac{24(300)}{720}$$
$$=\frac{10(720)}{720}$$
$$=10$$